# linux diff -U0 dropping code for a file and its formatted version

Tags: c, diff

I want to get diff hunks for a file and its formatted version. The original file is test.c.orig. The formatted version is test.c. The command used to get the diff hunks is  `diff -U0 test.c.orig test.c`. The problem is that the diff hunks produced is deleting code.

test.c.orig is

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int test_func() {
  int result = NO_ERROR;
 
  test1();
  test2();
  test3();
  test4();
 
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    test();
 
    test3();
    test4();
 
#ifdef BUILD
    result |= test_cleanup();
#endif
  }
 
  printf(".. done with %d\n", result);
  return result;
}
```

test.c is

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int test_func()
{
    int result = NO_ERROR;
 
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    test4();
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        test();
 
        test3();
        test4();
 
#ifdef BUILD
        result |= test_cleanup();
#endif
    }
 
    printf(".. done with %d\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

The diff hunk produced is

```
--- test.c.orig 2022-10-18 15:43:41.561416704 -0700
+++ test.c  2022-10-18 15:43:41.597417082 -0700
@@ -4,10 +4,3 @@
-int test_func() {
-  int result = NO_ERROR;
-
-  test1();
-  test2();
-  test3();
-  test4();
-
-  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
-    test();
+int test_func()
+{
+    int result = NO_ERROR;
@@ -14,0 +8,2 @@
+    test1();
+    test2();
@@ -17,0 +13,6 @@
+    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
+        test();
+
+        test3();
+        test4();
+
@@ -19 +20 @@
-    result |= test_cleanup();
+        result |= test_cleanup();
@@ -21 +22 @@
-  }
+    }
@@ -23,2 +24,2 @@
-  printf(".. done with %d\n", result);
-  return result;
+    printf(".. done with %d\n", result);
+    return result;
```

It can be seen here that the lines

```
  test3();
  test4();
```

are dropped.

The diff version used is

```
$ diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.8
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Eggert, Mike Haertel, David Hayes,
Richard Stallman, and Len Tower.
```

Any suggestions on how to get the correct output.

Comment: Using `-U0` (having 0 lines of context) is somewhat screwy. Try: `-u` instead (which, AFAICT, is `-U3`). The latter doesn't have the issues you're talking about. I've rarely seen diffs with other than 3 context lines (it's a good compromise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct, no lines are dropped.

The lines you are missing are still there, but are at the lines 15 and 16 of the original file.

You might want to reproduce it manually. Start from the end, for easier line identification.

Comment: I verified the lines are not dropped. It looks very confusing though.

Comment: Yes, but the output is not meant for human beings. At least not the usual ones. ;-)